# How to create a forum through the disqus-python api and increase the engagement?

Tags: python, api, blogs, disqus

The code I've tried:

```
disqus = DisqusAPI(secret_key, public_key)
disqus.post('forums.create',website="xxx.com",name="somename",short_name="sn")
```

I'm trying to create a forum automatically on disqus from every post on my blog. Is it possible? Is it the right way to do it?

What I want to achieve is create a discussion or something to get more engagement and traffic to my blog. So I'm looking at discuss api to help me with that. Then I can use the discuss as a new channel to people find content on my blog. Is it possible? Does it work like that? If I can't do it what is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: What wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the disqus team and this functionality is not current available. Byt the way they are disqusing with the dev team to include this feature.